# PHP Save Time HH:MM in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to save time `HH:MM` in MySQL.

Better option is to save using `strtotime` PHP function as TIMESTAMP or `HH:MM:00` as TIME?

Comment: I`d use timestamp if I would need different types of calculus

Comment: If You use `strtotime` consider using MySQLs TIMESTAMP datatype.

Comment: But whats the better option? strtotime as TIMESTAMP or HH:MM:00 as TIME?

Comment: date("Y-m-d H:i:s") is a good short term solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on how you will be processing the dates. If you prefer to do date calculations in MySQL, then most of it's functions work with DateTimes (or Times). Alternatively, if you're processing the dates in PHP most functions rely on timestamps, so they may be the way to go.

Another consideration to take into account is the range of dates you'll be storing. Timestamps will eventually run out in 2038, whereas MySQL DateTimes will carry on well into the future. I know you're only storing times, not dates... so this may not concern you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Wow, crazy times! Did not know about the 2038 issue.

Comment: I didn't know too, good learning heheh. By the way I'll store it as DATE H:i:s and use my model to convert it to H:i. Thanks

Comment: Sounds good. Keep in mind that `strtotime` is good at converting MySQL DateTimes or Times into Unix Timestamps (for use in PHP's date() function etc.).